# how to get maven-jaxws-plugin to generate @XmlElementWrapper on classes generated from xsd?

Tags: wsimport, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jax-ws-customization, jaxb-xew-plugin

I am using maven-jaxws-plugin to generate java classes from my wsdl, schema.  It is not generating the @XmlElementWrapper annotation in the generated classes.  From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447091/how-generate-xmlelementwrapper-annotation-with-xjc-and-customized-binding?rq=1) post I understand I nedd to use the jaxb-xew-plugin but am unable to get it working with the maven-jaxws-plugin.  Any help would be appreciated.
Here is the config I tried

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <xjcArgs>
                    <xjcArg>-no-header</xjcArg>
                    <xjcArg>-Xxew</xjcArg>
                    <xjcArg>-Xxew:instantiate lazy</xjcArg>
                    <xjcArg>-Xxew:delete</xjcArg>
                </xjcArgs>
                <extension>true</extension>

                <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</wsdlDirectory>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>attribute-service.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated</sourceDestDir>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <keep>true</keep>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-xew-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If it can only be integrated with the maven-jaxb2-plugin can you please help me get my webservice up?  Essentially How do I specify the wsdl and how to generate the Service classes?  (with @WebService annotation)

Thanks,

Bhagya

Answer (score 3):

although this post is 10 months old at the time of my writing, I answer it in case someone would need it.

with  jaxws-maven-plugin and with the help of jaxb-xew-plugin you can generate @XmlElementWrapper annotation for your list/array objects

assuming your wsdl has schema like:

```
<xs:element name="books" minOccurs="0" >
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="book" type="Book" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

it generates java as:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "books")
@XmlElement(name = "book")
protected List<Book> books;
```

and here is the build/plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
    <configuration>
        <wsdlDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/</wsdlDirectory>
        <xjcArgs>
            <xjcArg>-no-header</xjcArg>
            <xjcArg>-Xxew</xjcArg>
            <xjcArg>-Xxew:instantiate lazy</xjcArg>
            <xjcArg>-Xxew:delete</xjcArg>
        </xjcArgs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>wsdl_import</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xew-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4-1</version>
        </dependency>                   
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. I had to put the xjcArgs element in the first configuration block, or the arguments didn't get passed (maven 3.1.0). Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are configuration examples for the jaxws maven plugin available on the [sample page of the jaxb xew plugin](https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin/tree/master/samples). jaxws-maven-plugin 2.3.1-b03 work fine with jaxb-xew-plugin 1.2.