# wsimport/xjc command line plugins

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, wsimport, jaxb-xew-plugin

I have just successfully used a wsimport/xjc plugin named [xew](https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin) with maven, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246950/how-to-get-maven-jaxws-plugin-to-generate-xmlelementwrapper-on-classes-generate) post.

Using Maven for this at my company is currently not an option, so I'm trying to use the wsimport utility from the Java 7 SDK.

How do I tell wsimport to include the xew xjc plugin when importing my WSDL?

My current command line is:

```
wsimport -Xdebug -s src\main\java -d target\classes -extension -B-extension -B-classpath target\dependency\*:. -B-Xxew:instantiate lazy -B-Xxew:delete src\main\java\test.wsdl
```

It won't eat the -B parameters yet though: `no such JAXB option: -Xxew`.
The xew plugin and jaxb-xjc.jar are in the working directory and on the system CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went along and used Ant to convert my WSDL to code. For this, I downloaded jaxws-ri  version 2.2.8 and came up with the following Ant script, which works. Now I can use the maven-antrun-plugin to call on the script.

```
<project>

    <property name="jaxws.home" location="lib/jaxws-ri" />

    <path id="jaxws.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${jaxws.home}/lib" includes="jaxws-tools.jar" />
    </path>

    <taskdef classpathref="jaxws.classpath" name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport" />

    <wsimport keep="true" sourcedestdir="src/main/java" destdir="target/classes" extension="true" wsdl="src/main/java/test.wsdl">
        <xjcarg value="-cp" />
        <xjcarg file="lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar" />
        <xjcarg value="-cp" />
        <xjcarg file="lib/jaxb-xew-plugin-1.1.jar" />
        <xjcarg value="-Xxew" />
        <xjcarg value="-Xxew:instantiate lazy"/>
        <xjcarg value="-Xxew:delete"/>
    </wsimport>

</project>
```

Comment: I have so many questions! What is the command you ran? ant? Where was this file created? What is the name of this file? How did you pass it to ant? What all JARs did you download to your lib/ folder?

Comment: These are basic Ant questions. I recommend reading up about Ant.