# JAX-WS: XmlElementWrapper produces extra client code

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

I have some service with some WebMethod that returns object of Foo class:

```
public class Foo {

    private List<Detail> detailList;

    @XmlElement(name = "detail")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "detailList")
    public List<Detail> getDetailList() {
        return detailList;
    }

    public void setDetailList(List<Detail> value) {
        this.detailList = value;
    }

    public Foo() {
        this.detailList = new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

This code produces proper XML like:

```
<detailList>
    <detail>
        <key></key>
        <value></value>
    </detail>
    <detail>
        <key></key>
        <value></value>
    </detail>
<detailList/>
```

After building client JAR library it works OK.
But I really don't like the code I need to call to get the List:

```
foo.getDetailList().getDetail();
```

Because getDetailList() returns DetailList object.
How can I have getDetailList() method returning List **without any changes in above XML?**

Comment: Check out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447091/how-generate-xmlelementwrapper-annotation-with-xjc-and-customized-binding

Answer (score 0):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Root", propOrder = {
    "detailList"
})
public class Foo {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "detailList", required = true)
    @XmlElement(name = "detail")
    private List<Detail> detailList;

    public List<Detail> getDetailList() {
        return detailList;
    }

    public void setDetailList(List<Detail> value) {
        this.detailList = value;
    }

    public Foo() {
        this.detailList = new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but changing access type has no effect. wsimport still generates inner class Foo.DetailList with getDetail() method